# QTextBrowser / C++ append clickable text

Tags: c++, qt

I am new in using QT and i have a problem.
I want to check a 2D circuit layout and I want to output warnings or errors on a window. Each warning or error should contain X and Y coordinates and when I click
on a warning it should call a function which navigates me to the faulty position
in the layout(coordinate system).

Is there a way to make a text funcioning ?
I hope you understood my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be implemented with the `QTextBrowser`, but there will be a lot of code and no benefits. There is a faster, simpler and more scalable way.

Just use `QListWidget` and set user data (`QListWidgetItem::setData`) to each item, that will contain coordinates (you can use `QPoint` for this).

Create `QListWidget` and connect some slot or function to the signal `QListWidget::itemClicked`:

```
QListWidget* log = new QListWidget;
QObject::connect(log, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*));
```

Then, when you recieve new warning (ex. in `QString` called `log_string`) with coordinates (called `x` and `y`):

```
QListWidgetItem* line = new QListWidgetItem(log_string, log);
line->setData(Qt::UserRole, QVariant(QPoint(x, y)));
log->addItem(line);
```

Now you only need to process coordinates in the proper way in the slot or function connected to the `QListWidget::itemClicked` signal:

```
void onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
  const QPoint coord = item->data(Qt::UserRole).toPoint();
  // process coord.x() and coord.y()
}
```